# sql other display

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this query here :

```
 select  RSP,DATEDIFF(HOUR,date,GETDATE()) as 'age'
 from en_cours 
  left join Base_Client 
  on raison_sociale = Base_Client.Client or site_client = Base_Client.Client 
 group by RSP,DATEDIFF(HOUR,date,GETDATE()),ticket_cp
```

it' returne :

```
A | 1
A | 2
A | 10

B | 1
B | 4
B | 9
C | 10
C | 10
C | 13
```

is there any way to make it like that

```
A|1|2|10
B|1|4|9
C|10|10|13
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name look at my question againe , i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT RSP, MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN AGE END) [1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN AGE END) [2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN AGE END) [3]
FROM (
      SELECT RSP, DATEDIFF(HOUR,date,GETDATE()) as 'AGE', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RSP ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
      FROM en_cours  LEFT JOIN Base_Client ON raison_sociale = Base_Client.Client or site_client = Base_Client.Client 
) X
GROUP BY RSP
```